# Why Silex return "The requested URL /home was not found on this server." error message?

Tags: routes, silex

It is the first time I play with Silex. I've tried a '/' route, in GET and POST, and all works fine. Now I am trying to make more complex requests:

```
<?php

    require_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';
    $app = new Silex\Application();
    $app->get(
        '/home',
        function () use ($app) {
            return 'Homepage';
        }
    );
    $app->run();
```

"/home" route returns "The requested URL /home was not found on this server.". Why?

This is my .htaccess:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FIOLNAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

"/index.php/home" works

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try `index.php/home`. If that works you are missing the .htaccess (on Apache).

Take a look here http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/web_servers.html

Comment: Mmmm .htaccess is present. I've update my question. But Still dont work routes without "index.php"

Comment: I suppose this means I've a bad configuration in my machine.

Comment: Make sure `mod_rewrite` is enabled in Apache and `AllowOverride` is properly configured to read your `.htaccess`

Comment: What is the right AllowOverride configuration? "AllowOverride Yes"?

Comment: Ok, I am not able to configure properly my Apache webserver. Please, can you tell me where I have to set AllowOverride abd how?

Comment: The value should be `All`. You can check the reference here http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride.

Comment: I'd suggest you create a new question for this problem if you have no idea where to start, because the "where" part of your question depends on your server setup.

Comment: You can also search here for an existing question http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=AllowOverride

Comment: I'll thank you. I am afraid that my MAMP installation and its Apace configuration need a new question as you suggest.

Answer (score 4):

This should do the work :

```
$ sudo a2enmod rewrite
$ sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: Explanation: This will enable rewrite within  Apache2 configuration. It works!